# Failed to register device

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

When I run `googlesamples-assistant-pushtotalk --device-model-id 'my-model-id' project-id 'my-project-id'`
I get the following error:

```
NFO:root:Connecting to embeddedassistant.googleapis.com
WARNING:root:Device config not found: [Errno 2] No such file or 
directory: '/Users/rick/Library/Application Support/googlesamples-
assistant/device_config.json'
INFO:root:Registering device
ERROR:root:Failed to register device: {
"error": {
     "code": 403,
     "message": "Could not create the device instance. Account doesn't have permission to perform this operation for project sign-language-with-nao. See https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/library/python/embed/register-device",
     "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
     }
}
```

I used `google-oauthlib-tool` and confirmed access with the account of the projects owner.
I also set up a device-model (with `googlesamples-assistant-devicetool register-model`) which worked fine.
I'm on mac using python 3.6 and google-assistant-sdk 0.4.2

Any Ideas what permissions are missing? I made sure my Account is the owner of the project.

Comment: Did the `client_secret` you download come from that project? And when you were generating the `credentials.json` did the project name match what you expect?

Comment: Yes, the `client_secret` came from that project. However there is no project in the credentials.json (the one that is located in .../google-oauthlib-tool/credentials.json) it contains
`{"refresh_token": "XXX", "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token", "client_id": "SOME_ID", "client_secret": "XXX", "scopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/assistant-sdk-prototype"]}`

the client_id is listed as an OAuth 2.0 client ID on the projects page (https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials)

Comment: When you generate the credentials, you need to login and authorize your application. Is the app you're authorizing the one you want to authorize?

Answer (score 0):

Check the .asoundrc file on the /home/pi folder.  Mine did the same thing because I had extra commands in that file that mucked everything up.